# Is it possible for vscode to show git diffs condensed by hunks like SourceTree?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-diff

vscode seems to only show the whole file, but I would like to see just the bits that changed condensed by hunks like in SourceTree. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still not currently possible (April 2020), but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43887) in the repository.